# Select not the Slashed rows in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a column named CODES in a table CODE_DETAILS which contains values such as

ABCD\DRD,
ABCD\X\1,
ABCD\X\2,
ABCD\Y\7,
ABCD\PRE

I want to select all the rows starting with ABCD\ but I do not want the rows ending in X\1, X\2 and Y\7

Comment: On what basis? Exclude any ending with those specific values, or any with two `\` characters, or with two of those and the middle portion is `X` or `Y`, or something else? And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with the regular `like`:

```
where codes like 'ABCD\%' and
      codes not like '%X\1' and
      codes not like `%X\2' and
      codes not like `%Y\7'
```

Regular expressions are much more powerful than the standard SQL `like` operator.  But, `like` is portable among databases and much simpler to understand.

Comment: Backslash is NOT an escape symbol in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specifically exclude codes ending in `X\1`, `X\2` and `Y\7`, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM code_details
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (codes, '^ABCD\\')
  AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE(codes, '((X\\1)|(X\\2)|(Y\\7))$')
```

Comment: OK. I figured it out. :-)

SELECT CODE FROM CODE_DETAILS
WHERE CODE  LIKE '____/___'
 AND CODE NOT LIKE '____/_/_';